# Decompiled APK with apktool has hex digits in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, apktool

I tried to decompile the apk with apktool, modify it a bit, and re-build the apk.

Here is what I've tried:

1. `apktool d viber.apk`
2. Modified `res/xml/android_backup_rules_api31.xml` and `res/xml/android_backup_rules.xml`
3. `apktool b viber`

... and step 3 cannot proceed because of the error below:

```
W: /Users/<USERNAME>/Desktop/APK_RE/viber/AndroidManifest.xml:1076: error: '@2114715648' is incompatible with attribute theme (attr) reference.
W: /Users/<USERNAME>/Desktop/APK_RE/viber/AndroidManifest.xml:1077: error: '@2114715648' is incompatible with attribute theme (attr) reference.
W: /Users/<USERNAME>/Desktop/APK_RE/viber/AndroidManifest.xml:1078: error: '@2114715648' is incompatible with attribute theme (attr) reference.
W: /Users/<USERNAME>/Desktop/APK_RE/viber/AndroidManifest.xml:1083: error: '@2114846720' is incompatible with attribute resource (attr) reference.
W: error: failed processing manifest.
brut.androlib.exceptions.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/var/folders/rt/1rw6721917xbtnmtznd812hx3873hr/T/brut_util_Jar_79656065772315295564857961138440605910.tmp, link, -o, /var/folders/rt/1rw6721917xbtnmtznd812hx3873hr/T/APKTOOL17872764973844080976.tmp, --package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 21, --target-sdk-version, 33, --version-code, 651217, --version-name, 21.3.2.0, --no-auto-version, --no-version-vectors, --no-version-transitions, --no-resource-deduping, --allow-reserved-package-id, --no-compile-sdk-metadata, -e, /var/folders/rt/1rw6721917xbtnmtznd812hx3873hr/T/APKTOOL13620375907382818829.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/<USERNAME>/Library/apktool/framework/1.apk, --manifest, /Users/<USERNAME>/Desktop/APK_RE/viber/AndroidManifest.xml, /Users/<USERNAME>/Desktop/APK_RE/viber/build/resources.zip
```

... and I checked associated lines (i.e., 1076, 1077, 1078, 1083), and noticed that:

```
<activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.snap.camerakit.LegalPromptActivity" android:theme="@2114715648"/>
<activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.snap.camerakit.LegalPrePromptVariantGActivity" android:theme="@2114715648"/>
<activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.snap.camerakit.diagnostics.DiagnosticsExportActivity" android:theme="@2114715648"/>
...
<meta-data android:name="com.android.vending.splits" android:resource="@2114846720"/>
```

They all comes with this @+digits string. I thought this was some decoding error, so I checked the original APK with ClassyShark.jar, and they look like:

```
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7E0C0000'
        name='com.snap.camerakit.LegalPromptActivity'
        exported='false'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7E0C0000'
        name='com.snap.camerakit.LegalPrePromptVariantGActivity'
        exported='false'>
    </activity>
    <activity
        theme='@res/0x7E0C0000'
        name='com.snap.camerakit.diagnostics.DiagnosticsExportActivity'
        exported='false'>
    </activity>
...
    <meta-data
        name='com.android.vending.splits'
        resource='@res/0x7E0E0000'>
    </meta-data>
```

Why are these fields filled with hex digits? Is there any way I can fix them, or can I ignore them? (I don't really care about these functions actually, and I only want to do some backup tests as you can see in step 2)

Comment: Usually the hex values belong to a string resource which is referenced but wasn't found by apktool. If you don't want to modify AndroidManifest.xml I would do it this way: Remove the failing attributes from AndroidManifest.xml, build the apk, extract the AndroidManifest.xml from the original APK and insert it into your rebuilt APK.

Comment: And I would recommend to use `apktool d -s viber.apk` for decompiling. This does not decompile the DEX files which saves a lot of time as you only want to modify some xml files. In addition it decreases the list of potential problems you can run into.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your reply. By "extract the AndroidManifest.xml from the original APK and insert it into your rebuilt APK", you mean to open the original apk with zip (e.g. 7z) and copy the manifest file to the new apk in the same way? Let me try...

Comment: Robert's solution worked. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert's answer in the comments worked:

1. Remove associated attributes
2. Build the apk
3. Use some zip utility (e.g. 7z) to extract the original `AndroidManifest.xml` and replace the same file in re-built apk